# None propagation to a value

Tags: rust

Is there a better way to propagate `None` into a **value** (not just return `None`), other that wrapping it into a function like this to allow use of `?` operator (value itself is `Option`)?

```rust
struct A {
    b: Option<B>
}

struct B {
    c: Option<C>
}

struct C {
    val: i32,
    val_optional: Option<i32>
}

fn propagate<T>(f: impl FnOnce() -> Option<T>) -> Option<T> {
    return f();
}

#[test]
fn foo() {
    let abcv = Some(A {b: Some(B {c: Some(C {val: 42, val_optional: Some(42)})})});
    let val = propagate(|| abcv?.b?.c?.val_optional);//why not allow just let val = abcv?.b?.c?.val_optional ?
    assert_eq!(val, Some(42));

    let ab = Some(A { b: Some(B { c: None }) });
    let val = propagate(|| ab?.b?.c?.val_optional);//why not allow just let val = abcv?.b?.c?.val_optional ?
    assert_eq!(val, None);



    let abcv = Some(A {b: Some(B {c: Some(C {val: 42, val_optional: Some(42)})})});
    let val = propagate(|| Some(abcv?.b?.c?.val));//why not allow just let val = Some(abcv?.b?.c?.val) ?
    assert_eq!(val, Some(42));

    let ab = Some(A { b: Some(B { c: None }) });
    let val = propagate(|| Some(ab?.b?.c?.val));//why not allow just let val = Some(abcv?.b?.c?.val) ?
    assert_eq!(val, None);
}
```

Comment: Where are you propagating `None` into a value? It looks like you're looking for ["try blocks"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/try-blocks.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```rust
let abcv = Some(A {
    b: Some(B {
        c: Some(C {
            val: 42,
            val_optional: Some(42),
        }),
    }),
});

// returns the option 'val_optional'
let val_optional: Option<i32> = abcv
    .and_then(|a| a.b)
    .and_then(|b| b.c)
    .and_then(|c| c.val_optional);

// you can then get the value or if its None, take 0
let res: i32 = val_optional.unwrap_or(0);
```

Comment: Or just `.and_then(|a| a.b?.c?.val_optional)`

Comment: Yes it can. It propagates `None`.

Answer (score 2):

The `?` operator on an `Option<T>` does an early `return None` when applied to a variable whose value is `None`. So in your second example, if you did (as you propose)

```
val = ab?.b?.c?.val_optional;
```

But `ab?.b?.c? == None`, then `foo()` would do an early return there (but the Rust compiler doesn't allow that because as you've written it, `foo()` returns `()` and not an optional).

So you want to call `ab?.b?.c?.val_optional` inside a function so that the early return doesn't make `foo()` return early. Though you don't really need `propagate()`, as you could just use a closure like this:

```
let val = (|| ab?.b?.c?.val_optional)();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is something the Rust developers are actively working on: [`try` blocks](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/try-blocks.html).

They are not ready yet (there are issues around inference), but they will likely look like:

```rust
#![feature(try_blocks)]

let val = try { Some(abcv?.b?.c?.val) };
```

In the meantime, you can use an immediately invoked closure as @Andrew suggested.